# Application deployment folder on JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

Is there any configuration to hot deploy war file AND extract it into a project folder besides the .deployed file so we can modify web.xml, persistence.xml, just like Tomcat and websphere?

Thank you

Comment: If this is during development, why do you need the war file at all? You can just use the folder deployment. Did I miss something?

Comment: @amarunowski Thanks, but this is not during development. We develop the application on tomcat but need to test it on JBoss Application server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet worked with Tomcat, so I'm not certain how the two would interact